# What is setText() in Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I have been looking for setting query string into a `Query` object in Hibernate. I found the method `setText()` but I cannot find the explanation of this method; neither in [interface docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html), nor in [implementation's](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/impl/AbstractQueryImpl.html).

It may look like "setting a Text type parameter" but then what is the difference from `setString()` method? So it looks a bit confusing to me.

What exactly does this method do? Is it handy?

And (how) can we set query string (HQL or SQL) after producing the Query object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's used for `CLOB` fields, like `setBinary` is used for `BLOB`s.

The query string is set when the Query object is created, with

`Query q = session.createQuery("MY HQL QUERY")`